# Testing if a point lies inside a hyper-rectangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I'm writing a program in which hyperrectangles are represented by products of closed intervals. So if the dimension is **k** I use two verctors to represent a hyperrectangle:

**min = (x_1,x_2,...,x_k)**, **max = (y_1,y_2,...,y_k)** where the hyperrect is the product **[x_1,y_1] x ... x [x_k,y_k]**

In my program I test whether a **k**-dim point lies inside the hyperrect or not. Here is how I do it, is it correct?

The point **p=(p_1,...,p_k)** lies inside the hyperrect if **x_i <= p_i <= y_i** for all **i=1,...,k**

Answer (score 0):

Yes (if you don't care about boundary cases).